# Find block pattern in many distinct files and selectively extract certain lines from it

Tags: shell-script, grep, find, regular-expression

I have tens of thousands of directories.  Each directory is named by number, like `1, 2, 3,...`  Each directory contains a large .dat file called `data.dat` and each file has a section that looks like this:

```
Configurations for Sm:

  Sm Nd H  O 

  0  1  4  0          1.00          7.14%
  1  0  3  0          3.00          7.14%
  0  0  5  0          1.00          7.14%
```

I care about the first two numbers on each line.  I want:

- All of the lines that start with `0  1` (in this example, that's the
  first line of numbers) to end up in a new file called `0-1.dat` with the file name (number) at the start of the line.  An example is below, called "example."
- Likewise, all of the lines that begin with `1  0` (here the second
  line) should end up in a file called `1-0.dat` with the file number at the start of the line.
- All lines that begin with `0  0` (here the third line) should go to a
  file called `0-0.dat`.

Complications for finding the lines I need are:

- Sometimes one of the lines might be missing or the lines might be in
  different order.
- Also, each file has many sections called `Configurations for X`,
  where X is some string.  So I do need to somehow use the identifier `Configurations for Sm:` and search the first set of numbers below it.

Example of what I want to achieve, where the first number on the line is the directory name/number containing the file from which the line was extracted:

```
Example
In file called 0-1.txt:
1    0  1  4  0          1.00          7.14%
2    0  1  7  1          1.00          7.14%
3    0  1 ....

In file called 1-0.txt:
1    1  0  1  0          1.00          7.14%
2    1  0  4  2          1.00          7.14%
3    1  0 ....
```

I currently have:

```
find . -name data.dat -exec grep "Configurations for Sm:" {} + > 0-1.txt
```

All this does though, is put anything that would come after `Configurations for Sm:` in a separate file.  I just cannot figure out how to do what I need to do--find lines below `Configurations for Sm:` by their number contents.  If anyone has any hints or could direct me to an online resource, I would be very grateful.  Thank you.

Comment: Can you have more than one section that starts witth `Configurations for Sm:` in any of your initial data.dat files ?

Comment: Thanks for your interest, @Cbhihe. No, that particular expression is unique. There are other expressions like it, but not identical. For example, "Configurations for Nd:"

Comment: Thank you so much, lgpasquale and bu5hman for your help. I am on the road and will try your solutions in a few hours as soon as I get home!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a combination of `sed` and `grep`.

Assuming all your directories `0`,`1`,`2`,... are in `/your/path` (e.g. `/your/path/0/data.dat`):

```bsh
for dir in /your/path/*; do
    idx=$(basename ${dir})
    sed -n '/Configurations for Sm:/,/Configurations for/p' ${dir}/data.dat | \
        grep '^ \+0 \+1' | \
        sed "s/^/${idx}/" >> "0-1.dat"
done
```

The first `sed` should extract only the portion of the file that is of interest (between the two patterns `Configurations for Sm:` and `Configurations for`)

`grep` matches `0 1` at the beginning of the line (with a positive number of spaces in-between)

The second sed adds the "index" (the directory name) at the beginning of the line.

The output is appended (`>>`) to "0-1.dat".

You could add an outer loop to test different combinations of `0` and `1`.

Note: I haven't properly tested this.

Answer (score 1):

How about an `awk` solution

```
awk '/^ *[0-1] +[0-1]/{
    n=split(FILENAME,d,"/");print d[n-1], $0 > $1"-"$2".txt"
}' $(find . -name "*.dat")
```

First `find` all of your `dat` files and feed them to `awk` but only process those lines which start`^` with 0 or 1 as the first 2 non-whitespace characters

```
/^ *[0-1] +[0-1]/
```

Then `split` the filename on `/` into an array, storing the number of elements in the array in `n`

```
n=split(FILENAME,d,"/")
```

Finally print the directory name/number (which is the `d[n-1]` element in your array) and the data from your `dat` file `$0` to a file composed of the first two values

```
print d[n-1], $0 > $1"-"$2".txt"
```

If you have 10's of thousands of files then the overhead in `split`ting `FILENAME` for every line may be too much, in which case you could loop over the files feeding each to `awk` and append to the collating files instead `>> $1"-"$2".txt"`

maybe....

```
find . -iname "*.dat" -print0 | xargs -0  -n 1 -P 0 awk 'NR==1{n=split(FILENAME,d,"/"); dir=d[n-1]}/ *[0-1] +[0-1]/{print dir, $0 >> $1"-"$2".txt"}'
```

Comment: I am going to try your solution right now.  I marked the earlier answer as correct because I tried it first, being less familiar with Awk.  However, I want to learn (particularly as I heard that it's faster--would be interested to know if that's true) and really appreciate that you took time to provide this.  Thank you.